# Global constraint in xib

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Is it possible to create constraint that can be used in different xibs ? So when I decide to change ie. a margin it'll change automatically in all my views.

I ws thinking about sublcassing `NSLayoutConstraint` but it's only possible to set constant property of this class and what if I want to use multiplier intead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create constraint that can be used in different xibs ? So when I decide to change ie. a margin it'll change automatically in all my views.

**No.** A given constraint is an actual object that refers to other specific objects, so you can't have a single constraint object that manages the relationships between multiple pairs of views.

> I ws thinking about sublcassing NSLayoutConstraint but it's only possible to set constant property of this class and what if I want to use multiplier intead?

To change `multiplier` you need to create a new constraint to replace the old one. There doesn't seem to be an easy way around this requirement.